Weird Issue, Ubuntu Server booting from disk failed after being copied from as a diskless boot image
I'm encountering weird issue when I was setting up a diskless (PXE booting) cluster of Ubuntu Server.
The diskless cluster was successfully built. But the original Ubuntu Server that the cluster was copied from could not boot from disk anymore.
I'm totally confused. Here's what I've just experienced.
The guide I was following: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto

Installed Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS on Machine A (On a SSD).

Mounted the NFS root folder from Machine B to Machine A using NFS protocol.


mount -t nfs -o nolock 192.168.1.2:/nfsroot /mnt


Copied the system files from Machine A to the NFS root folder on Machine B

# on machine A
cp -ax /. /mnt/.;
cp -ax /dev/. /mnt/dev/.


Setting up whatever need for a PXE boot (DHCP server, TFTP server, kernel image, etc.) Using a configuration like this:

LABEL ubuntu
MENU LABEL Ubuntu-22.04.03-5.15
KERNEL ubuntu/5.15/vmlinuz
APPEND root=/dev/nfs initrd=ubuntu/5.15/myinitrd.img netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.1.2:/nfsroot ip=dhcp rw

(Note: will change rw to r later)
Now other computers that boot via PXE can work as normal.
While when rebooting Machine A from disk without the NFS server, I tried to find an NFS-Server and can not boot from disk anymore.
nfsroot: need a path

And after retrying for 180s, it gave up and entered the (initramfs) prompt.
I moved the disk from Machine A to another computer and checked /etc/fstab and /etc/default/grub on the disk and did not find anything abnormal, neither mentioned anything NFS.
Another teammate of me tried this before, and got similiar result. I doubt if he actually did it correctly so I tried again, and resulted in the same.
